# How to integrate $\int x^n (1-x)^{n-t} dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Anyone knows how to integrate $\int x^n(1-x)^{n-t} dx$, where $n$ and $t$ are positive integes and $n \geq t$.

Thanks

Comment: The incomplete beta function [finite series](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Beta3/03/01/01/) works with a change of parameters

Comment: You have $dt$ in your title but $dx$ in your question.  Which integration variable do you intend?

Comment: Your title has $dt$ and your problem statement has $dx$.  Which to you want?

Comment: Do you need the indefinite integral, or only e.g. the definite integral from $0$ to $1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an elementary expression for this integral, [but according to Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5Bx%5En%281-x%29%5E%28n-t%29%2Cx%5D),

$$\int x^n (1-x)^{n-t} dx = B_x(n + 1, n - t + 1)$$

where $B_x$ denotes [the incomplete Beta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html).  This is a [Chebyshev integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevIntegral.html) with $p = n$ and $q = n - t$.

Answer (score 0):

Just consider $a:=x^n\cdot (1-x)^n$ to be one (parametrized) constant and $b:=1-x$ to be an other such. Then your integrand becomes $f(t)=a\cdot b^{-t}$. The remainder then should be obvious.

--- rk

Comment: $((1-x)^n)^{-t} = (1-x)^{-nt}$, not $(1-x)^{n-t}$...